# Need help before making the full character

Tags: modeling, workflow

I want to make a character for my game , but if I want the player to be able to change his clothes , should I make a full body for the character? Almost all game characters that I've seen don't have a body, its just conected to the clothes, but I don't know if I need the body. I havent started sculpting the face because of that. Help! Thanks

Comment: I'm not an expert on modeling for games however I'd start by making a body shape of the character, then use that body shape as a template for clothes. Then, once you have clothes, make two versions of the character. One version will be head, neck, hands and feet (or no feet). The other will be head, neck, hands, arms, legs and feet, or where ever the cut off point would be for shorts. 

Again, I'm no expert in how this is truly done in games, that's just how I'd go about doing it. :)

Comment: @Stewie please write your comment as an answer :)

Comment: still dont know XD, Stewie, thanks for the advice but i still need to know, does all the cloth need to be on a same blender file? so it could have the character weight ? =| i know that this needs scripting too, but need to know this first to be able to do it

Comment: Yes. put the clothes into the same blender file or link them into it. To build on stewie's idea you might want to make the cutoffs slightly above the clothes lines. this'll avoid any situations where you see randomly floating legs from odd angles. Especially with backface culling.

Comment: and if im goin to add like for example 150 cloth  ?